# UserCannotBeAlteredWithoutSessionError after SDK update

Tags: ios, sdk, parse-platform, upgrade

The parse SDK has recently been updated (from v1.2.19 to v1.4.1) and users registered with the old version of the SDK receive the error:

```
Error: Parse::UserCannotBeAlteredWithoutSessionError (Code: 206, Version: 1.4.1)
ERROR PFUser checkin: Error Domain=Parse Code=206 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Parse error 206.)" UserInfo=0x170e76380 {error=Parse::UserCannotBeAlteredWithoutSessionError, code=206}
```

when the app tries to save the current user object to the server, which for a logged-in user seems a pretty obvious thing to do.

The error code (based on the docs over Parse) means:

- **206** Error code indicating that a user object without a valid session could not be altered.

My guess would be to force the users to login again but that seems a bit harsh in the situation.

Has anyone else came across the same issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution:

This is actually not a bug and a result from going back and forth between two versions of the SDK. 
If you are just upgrading from v1.2.19 to v1.4.1 everything should be fine, but when you then go back to v1.2.19 to v1.4.1 you will run into this behavior.

There was a change of how we handle the session data that is stored between those versions and the path of downgrading -> upgrading -> downgrading is not supported. You should be able to reproduce this behavior by following these steps:

- Delete all app data from device ("Reset Content & Settings" in the iOS Simulator).
- Launch TestApp with 1.2.19 - No error in log
- Launch TestApp with 1.4.1 - No error in log
- Launch TestApp with 1.2.19 - No error in log
- Launch TestApp with 1.4.1 - Error in log

Answer (score 2):

If you still having issue, use below code to update the user with session token

```
[PFUser becomeInBackground:[PFUser currentUser].sessionToken block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
    currentUser = user;

}];
```